# dual-boot of mint and windows 8.1 doesnt work - mint doesnt appear

Tags: linux, partitioning, windows-8.1, multi-boot, linux-mint

I got a new laptop and installed Linux Mint 17 MATE and Windows 8.1. I want to use dual-boot so that I can choose at start-up which OS will appear. Now only the Windows appears and I dont get asked to choose.
So I used EasyBCD to try and fix it - I added the mint and now I get asked to choose OS but when I choose the mint, it doesnt appear and I just see the blinking prompt.

My partitions:
1 - 350MB for system windows - primary
2 - c:/ (windows) - primary
3 - d:/ (windows) - primary
4 - root (linux) - logical
5 - /home (linux) - logical
6 - swap (linux) - logical

How can I fix it? I understand I need to install GRUB in mint but I dont really understand linux...

Thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 0):

When installing a Linux on any Windows/Linux mix you install Linux SECOND because it installs GRUB as the bootloader which can find your Windows install and it then chainloads to the Windows bootloader correctly. You then get the choice of OSes.

For your situation you need to go to your Mint install and install GRUB and do a GRUB update so it locates your OSes.